# Where am I wrong here? I don't know why I can't get it

Tags: boolean-algebra

Question:

BOOLEAN SIMPLIFICATION:

Prove that F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+w’xy’z’+ w’x’yz

is equals to F(w,x,y,z) = y’z’ + wx’

My solution:

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+w’xy’z’+ w’x’yz**

Idempotence - (2nd row)w’xy’z’ + (6th row)w’xy’z’ = w’xy’z’

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+ w’x’yz**

Distribute - (1st row)w’x’y’z’ + (6th row)w’x’yz = w’x’ / (2nd row)w’xy’z’+ (3rd row)wx’y’z’ = y’z’ / (4th row)wx’y’z+ (5th row)wx’yz’ = wx’

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’ + y’z’+ wx’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’ + wx’ + y’z’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = x’ + (w + w’) + y’z’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = x’ + y’z’** is not Equal to **y’z’ + wx’**

What should I do?  What was wrong with what I did?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to prove is true. Substitute w=0 and you get F(0,x,y,z) = x'y'z' + xy'z' + xy'z' + x'yz = x'y'z' + xy'z' + x'yz = y'z'+x'yz which is not the same as y'z'.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the original formula for F. According to [this boolean simplifier](http://tma.main.jp/logic/logic.php?lang=en&type=eq&eq=%28%7Ew%29%28%7Ex%29%28%7Ey%29%28%7Ez%29+%2B+%28%7Ew%29x%28%7Ey%29%28%7Ez%29+%2B+w%28%7Ex%29%28%7Ey%29%28%7Ez%29+%2B+w%28%7Ex%29%28%7Ey%29z+%2B+w%28%7Ex%29y%28%7Ez%29+%2B+%28%7Ew%29x%28%7Ey%29%28%7Ez%29+%2B+%28%7Ew%29%28%7Ex%29yz) the minimal form of F is ~w~xyz + ~w~y~z + w~x~y + w~x~z.

Comment: This term is repeated: w’xy’z’

Comment: The question said my answer must be equal to y'z' + wx' but my answer was x' + y'z' which is wrong

Comment: @Andyaka through Idempotence to shorten to w'xy'z' + w'xy'z' = w'xy'z' which is 2nd and 6th row of the original problem

Comment: Perhaps Mr Karnaugh can help: ***The Karnaugh Map Boolean Algebraic Simplification Technique*** (Maurice Karnaugh, 1953) - HL Sneha, AAC, 2016jun24
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/karnaugh-map-boolean-algebraic-simplification-technique/

Comment: @DevilBlacklist I suspect there is an error in the terms. I mean, why would you repeat a term?

Comment: @tlfong01 we need to simply the problem without using k mapping

Comment: @Andyaka what do u mean?

Comment: @Devil Blacklist: Well, K-map visualizes what goes wrong in  ***x’ + y’z’ is not Equal to y’z’ + wx’***.

Comment: sorry @tlfong01  i don't have time to review that. I'll pass it on and I only have one hour left, I'm still busy solving something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements are erroneous:

- \$w’x’y’z’ + w’x’yz = w’x’\$
- \$w’xy’z’ + wx’y’z’ = y’z’\$
- \$wx’y’z + wx’yz’ = wx’\$

Note that \$y' z'\$ is not the negation of \$yz\$, because it's possible for \$y' z'\$ to be false but for \$yz\$ to also be false.

Applying distributivity correctly, we find that

- \$w’x’y’z’ + w’x’yz = w’x’ (y'z' + yz)\$
- \$w’xy’z’ + wx’y’z’ = y’z’ (w'x + wx')\$
- \$wx’y’z + wx’yz’ = wx’ (y'z + yz')\$

But this seems to be a dead end, since the right-hand sides of these aren't very easy to simplify. I think the best way to go is to try to distribute out one variable at a time. For example:

- \$w'x'y'z' + w'xy'z' = w'y'z'\$

---

With all that said, as some of the comments pointed out, \$w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+w’xy’z’+ w’x’yz\$ is *not* equal to \$y’z’ + wx’\$, so proving that they're equal is impossible. This can be seen by considering w = 1, x = 1, y = 0, z = 0. With these inputs, the former expression is false but the latter expression is true.

Answer (score 1):

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+w’xy’z’+ w’x’yz**

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’y’z’+w’xy’z’+ wx’y’z’+wx’y’z+ wx’yz’+ w’x’yz**

F(w,x,y,z) = (1st row)w’x’y’z’ + (6th row)w’x’yz = w’x’ / (2nd row)w’xy’z’+ (3rd row)wx’y’z’ = y’z’ / (4th row)wx’y’z+ (5th row)wx’yz’ = wx’

**Distributed is Equal to = 1**

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’(y’z’ + yz) + y’z’(w’x+wx’) + wx’ (y’z+yz’)**

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’(1) + y’z’(1) + wx’ (1)**

**F(w,x,y,z) = w’x’ + y’z’+ wx’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = (w’x’) + (y’z’)+ wx’**

**Distributed**

**F(w,x,y,z) = (w’y’ + w’z’ + x’y’ + x’z’)+ wx’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = (w’y’ + w’z’ + x’y’ + x’z’)+ wx’**

**Distributed w’y’ + x’y’ = y’(x’+w’) / w’z’ + x’z’ = z’(x’+w’)**

**F(w,x,y,z) = y’(x’+w’) + z’(x’+w’) + wx’**

**Switch y’(x’+w’) + z’(x’+w’)**

**F(w,x,y,z) = y’z’ + (x’+w’) / (x’+w’) + wx’**

**F(w,x,y,z) = y’z’ + wx’**

Comment: y’z’ + yz does not equal 1. Try y=0 and z=1.